# Explaining some ASM

Tags: assembly, x86, reverse-engineering, dos

I've got this ASM code and i need help explaing it, mainly the macro. I've tried a ASM to C disassembly tool, but couldn't get it to work with multiple files and the others were far above my budget.
macro.inc:

```
pokazvane_cifra_dl macro
```

```
push ax
push dx
```

```
ad dl,30h
mov ah, 02h
int 21h

pop dx
pop ax
endm

exit macro

mov ah,4ch
int 21h
endm

pokazvane_znak_dl macro nomer_znak

push ax
push dx
mov dl, nomer_znak
mov ah,02h
int 21h
pop dx
pop ax

endm

eho_al macro
push ax
mov ah, 02h
int 21h
pop ax

endm
```

program.asm:

```
include macro.inc
```

`.model small
.stack 100h
.data
.code
start:
    mov cx,5
povtori1:
    mov ah,01h
    int 21h
    mov ah,0h
    push ax
    loop povtori1
    pokazvane_znak_dl 10d
    pokazvane_znak_dl 13d`

mov cx, 5 
povtori2:
pop dx
mov ah, 02h
int 21h
loop povtori2
exit
end start

Any and all help will be appreciated.

Comment: **The** macro? There are like 4... which one? Have you consulted a DOS interrupt reference?

Comment: Is this your native language? They seem pretty explanatory names, what can't you understand?

Comment: @Jester As hard as I look, I can only see 3.

Comment: @tofro take into account broken formatting... :) there are 4.

Comment: Maybe before trying to reverse engineer any assembly undertake an Assembly course first, so you will understand what the instructions do. RE is actually often a bit harder, than writing your own code, so it makes little sense to try to do RE, if you don't understand even such trivial code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pokazvane_cifra_dl macro`: displays value `dl+48` as ASCII character.

If `dl` is value from `0` to `9`, it will show the according ASCII digit `'0'`-`'9'`, so that the reason why the name of macro is something like "display digit" (although you may also call it with for example `dl = 40` and it will display ASCII char `'X'`).

---

`exit macro`: returns control back to DOS (the whole source is DOS-platform targetted, ie. 16 bit real mode x86 assembly with `int 21h` used for system services, ie needs DOS-like operating system to work).

---

`pokazvane_znak_dl macro`: is slight variation on the first one, this time displaying any ASCII character, like `pokazvane_znak_dl 'X'` to display `'X'`.

---

`eho_al macro`: does display ASCII character from `dl`. Not sure why the name says `eho_al`, while it will not use `al` at all, instead it would destroy the value in `al`, if it wouldn't do `push/pop ax` around the `int 21h`.

---

The code itself:

- will read 5 characters (ASCII) from input, and `push` them on the stack
- display two characters `10` and `13` to create "new line" (the proper sequence in DOS is `13` `10`, the other way).
- then it will pop those 5 chars one by one back from stack, and display each on screen.
- exits to DOS.

I didn't verify there's no bug in the code, but **if** it is bug free, then the output should look like:

```
$prompt> exe.exe
    abcde
    edcba$prompt>
```

I'm not sure where the DOS prompt will land after execution, whether DOS will insert additional new line, or it will land as I imagined it above. The first "abcde" is input from user, the second is display done by the code.

---

EDIT: I forgot that push+pop in loops for input/output will effectively reverse the input "string", as *stack* is LIFO (Last In First Out) type of queue/container (I still didn't bother to really compile it and run it, so in case you really need 100% answer what the code does, run it).

Comment: Thank you so much, you're a life savior.